# How to determine what decorators a view has in Django?

Tags: django

I know the relative url (ie. /accounts/) and from that I'd like to determine whether or not the view that handles it is decorated with the login_required decorator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a function has a decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489649/check-if-a-function-has-a-decorator)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the corresponding view from an URL using django.urls.resolve.

As of determining how it was decorated, this is impossible. A decorator is the application of a function, not some sort of flag.

However you can redefine your own `login_required` decorator that calls the original `login_required` AND sets a custom attribute to the view: `view.is_login_required = True`.