# Check if a view has a decorator flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I want to somehow check if a endpoint has a decorator like `login_required`, is there a way I could do it?
This is how I get all url_rules:

```
def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


def sitemap():
    links = []
    for rule in 
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = flask.url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    return links
```

This is my navigation bar in which I use these, but I want to somehow not display the views who have the decorator login_required.

```
{% for url, endpoint in endpoints %}
            {% if request.url_rule != endpoint %}
                <a  href="{{ url }}">
                <button class="tablecontent">{{ endpoint.split('.', 1)[1] }}</button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

I am sorry for the late edit, but if someone is still here, any help would be appreciated. Or maybe I should better hard code the view names in a dictionary?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Like something that I could use to see if a view for example add_photo has a decorator called login_required, that could look something like this url.needs_login

Comment: I still don't understand "like something that I could use to see if a view" makes no sense. you can do if statements. Also to login required has it. You can check if the user is authenticated instead.

Comment: @MareksNo It would be better if you elaborate why you want to do this and show some code if possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a function has a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489649/check-if-a-function-has-a-decorator)

Comment: If flask has func_dict I guess it shpuld work, I will try this out when I get on my  computer, thank you